# eclipselink without persistence.xml

Tags: eclipselink, persistence.xml

I'm not a big fan of XML files. **Therefore I'm wondering if there is a way to use eclipselink without its persistence.xml configuration file.** Why?

Because I want to manage different databases dynamically. It would be much easier to do it without the XML file.

I'm surprised that I couldn't find anything on the web for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really, but you could create an EclipseLink ServerSession directly and wrap it with an EntityManagerFactoryImpl, but I would not suggest it.

You would be better off creating a persistence.xml.  You can still do dynamic databases, you just need to pass a properties file to createEntityManagerFactory(Map) that include your database info.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. At the end of this Java file is an example: http://dev.eclipse.org/svnroot/rt/org.eclipse.persistence/trunk/jpa/eclipselink.jpa.test/src/org/eclipse/persistence/testing/tests/jpa/performance/JPAConcurrencyComparisonModel.java

Answer (score 0):

Though it is not an direct answer to your question, this will help for the second part of your question. For managin multiple database connections, you can define multiple server sessions in sessions.xml and access those where you want.

you may use follwoing lines for accessing particular session

```
ServerSession aSession =   = (ServerSession) SessionManager.getManager().getSession("session_2");
```

Comment: Nice input but as you already mentioned, not exactly what I was looking for.